# Integrating Unity with Salesforce

Tags: unity-game-engine, salesforce, webgl, integration, unity-webgl

I hope you're all doing well. I'm currently working on a project where I'm aiming to integrate Unity with Salesforce. My approach involves building the Unity project into WebGL and then uploading it to a Salesforce Lightning Web Component (LWC) project.

However, I've hit a roadblock with this integration. Even the basic step of uploading the WebGL files to the LWC project is causing errors, and it seems that the files are not being accepted by the platform.

I'm curious if anyone in the community has successfully achieved a similar integration before. Specifically, I'd like to know if there are any best practices, tips, or guidelines for integrating Unity (WebGL) projects with Salesforce LWC. Are there any potential pitfalls to watch out for?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, experiences, or advice that anyone can provide. If you've encountered similar challenges or have successfully integrated Unity with Salesforce, your input could be extremely valuable to me.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read my question and share your expertise.

Best regards,

Comment: Please share the error details.